# Replacing PHP "undefined variable" error?

Tags: php, dictionary, undefined

so basically I want to make an online dictionary, the word to be searched for is introduced by an input, and I want to make so that if it can't find the word+definition in db to say a message like "We couldn't find any definition" or something like that, in my code because it can't find it , it ways "undefined variable"

```
<?php
include ("header.php");
$search = $_POST['se'];
include ("connect.php");

$dictionary=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `dictionary` WHERE word = '$search'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $dictionary )) {
    $word=$row['word'];
    $description=$row['definition'];
    }
                    echo "<div class=\"webResult\">
                    <h2>$word</h2>
                    <p>$description</p>
                    </div>";
include ("footer.php");
?>
```

P.S.: I know my code is vulnerable to SQLi , but I'll fix that later.

Comment: On which line do you get that undefined variable error ?

Comment: 13,14 but they happen because my $word and $definiton are empty, and this happens because my query didn't found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $dictionary )) {
    $word=$row['word'];
    $description=$row['definition'];

    echo "<div class=\"webResult\">
    <h2>$word</h2>
    <p>$description</p>
    </div>";
} else {
    echo "$search not found";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try wrapping the undefined vars in `isset`

```
if (isset($word) && isset($description)) {
    echo "<div class=\"webResult\">
    <h2>$word</h2>
    <p>$description</p>
    </div>";
}
else {
    echo "Nothing found";
}
```

Same goes for `$search = $_POST['se'];`

```
if(!isset($_POST['se'])) {
    echo "Nothing found";
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $dictionary )) {

    $word=$row['word'];
    $description=$row['definition'];

 }
if(!empty($word) && !empty($description)){

      echo '<div class=\"webResult\">';
      echo '<h2>$word</h2>';
      echo '<p>$description</p>';
      echo '</div>"; 

}else{
  echo 'could not find your word';
}


include ("footer.php");
?>
```

You have to validate your variables if its have value or not

Answer (score 0):

The variables `$word` and `$description` are first created inside the `while` loop. This means that they do not have any [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) outside it. This should be the most probable cause, since you are getting a `variable not defined` error.

There are a couple of options here.

**One**, you could create these variables *outside* the `while` loop, and then assign them new values as you are doing now. Here is what your code might look like, if you choose to do it this way:

```
$search = $con->escape_string($_POST['se']);
$dictionary = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `dictionary` WHERE word = '$search'");
$word = "";
$description = "";

while($row = $dictionary->fetch_assoc())
{
    $word = $row['word'];
    $description = $row['definition'];
}

if (!empty($word) && !empty($description))
{
    echo '<div class="webResult"><h2>' . $word . '</h2><p>' . $description . '</p></div>';
}
else
{
   echo "We couldn't find any definition";
}
```

This will work for you if you have multiple results in the returned `mysqli_resource`, and want to use the last in the list.

**Two**, if you are likely to get only one result returned, or if you just want to use the first result in the list, you can have the `echo` statement *inside* an `if` statement that checks if a valid result is returned. For example:

```
$search = $con->escape_string($_POST['se']);
$dictionary = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `dictionary` WHERE word = '$search'");
$word = "";
$description = "";

$row = $dictionary->fetch_assoc();

if($row)
{
    $word = $row['word'];
    $description = $row['definition'];

    if (!empty($word) && !empty($description))
    {
        echo '<div class="webResult"><h2>' . $word . '</h2><p>' . $description . '</p></div>';
    }
    else
    {
       echo "We couldn't find any definition";
    }
}
```

---

#### Note:

In the above examples, we use `!empty()` to check the variables. This is because `isset()` is pointless here, since we have already created (set) the variables ourselves.

#### Things to read up:

- Scope of variables - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php
- `empty()` function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php
- Object oriented `mysqli` - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
include ("header.php");
$search = $_POST['se'];
include ("connect.php");

$dictionary=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `dictionary` WHERE word = '$search'");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $dictionary )) {
    $word=$row['word'];
    $description=$row['definition'];
    }

if(isset($word)){
               echo "<div class=\"webResult\">
                    <h2>$word</h2>
                    <p>$description</p>
                    </div>";
}
else{
    echo "We couldn't find any definition";
}
include ("footer.php");
```

Comment: Perhaps it's simple for you and me but not someone else so you should consider adding a short description about what's so simple.